# Prove $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{d^{2n}}{dz^{2n}}(z^2-1)^{2n}=(-1)^n\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\right)^2 $

Tags: derivatives

Prove the formula:
$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{d^{2n}}{dz^{2n}}(z^2-1)^{2n}=(-1)^n\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\right)^2.$$

The only way I can conceive to move forward with my limited background is to try induction. Base case obviously checks out, next try to use the assumption the formula works for $n$ to get it for $n+1$:
$$\frac{d^{2n}}{dz^{2n}}(\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(z^2-1)^{2n+2})\\
=\frac{d^{2n}}{dz^{2n}}(2z(2n+2)(2n+1)(z^2-1)^{2n}+2(2n+2)(z^2-1)^{2n+1}).$$
Now I am stuck, since if I want to use the formula for $n$ in the first term I can't because of the extra $z$, and in the second term I can't because of the $2n+1$ power term.

Can anyone help please?

Editing again:

In the second term I can actually split of the extra $(z^2-1)$ factor, leading to:
$$\frac{d^{2n}}{dz^{2n}}(-1)2(2n+2)(z^2-1)^{2n}.$$

Assuming all the other factors will go to $0$ because of the limit (?), we can compare
$$(-1)(4n+4)A_{n}$$
to the original formula for $n$ where I call the right side ($(-1)^n\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\right)^2$) $A_n$.
Now substituting $n+1$ for $n$ in $A_n$, leads me to
$$(\frac{2n!}{n!})^2(\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)})^2,$$
where the second factor does not equal to $(4n+4)$, meaning my approach is the incorrect approach. So I am stuck a bit deeper.
Btw, this is a textbook exercise for self study.

Final edit:

Using the binomial theorem as recommended by Gary in the comments made it pretty easy. So the remaining question is solved. What remains unsolved is why I got the inequality in the end when trying induction, so I am doing something wrong. You are welcome to point out what, but of course this warrants a new question. In any case thank you all.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts."

Comment: Your formula is a product. This implies a recursion with multiplication. So one way is to prove by induction.

Comment: Issue connected with the Legendre polynomial $P_{2n}$.

Comment: I edited the question to mention my own thoughts. Induction indeed is what I have been trying most, without getting far unfortunately. Legendre polynomials are over my head I think.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem for $(z^2-1)^{2n}$.

Comment: Yes! Using the binomial theorem works, and was pretty easy.